# Write data from csv to Postgres using Python and overwrite existing rows

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am currently exporting a csv file to a Postgres database, however if I do this operation multiple times, the same rows happen to be duplicated in the database.

How can I modify my code to overwrite existing rows to avoid duplication?

```
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    cur.copy_from(f, 'table1', sep=',')
            
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you did to learn about what is going wrong. Did you check documentation and is there something you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with `COPY`.

You could use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`, but that necessitates that you create a unique constraint or index that defines what you mean by "duplicate".